# Max ID from table as integer

Tags: php, mysql

So i want to select highest (or latest) id from my table  and use it for loop "for".

I did like this:

```html
$sql1="SELECT MAX(id_i) FROM images;";
$max_id=  mysqli_query($link, $sql1);

for($i=0;$i<=$max_id;$i++)
{
...
}
```

But i get an error that : Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int :/

Comment: That's exactly what's happening you're trying to use an object as an int. You actually need to retrieve the results. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for return types of mysqli_query.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just use a `foreach`? Sounds and looks like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @PeeHaa: maybe he'll use the value somewhere else? I guess...I dunno I'm just saiyan.

Comment: Op does a loop through the recordset either way so no need at all for a separate query for it, because (when sorted correctly) you would have the same id either way.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

```
$sql1="SELECT MAX(id_i) as max_id FROM images;";
$result=  mysqli_query($link, $sql1);


//for loop
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
for($i=0;$i<=$row->max_id;$i++)
{
...
}

//or using while (recommended)
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) 
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Andrew P. wrote on his comment, mysqli_query returns an object not an int. From documentation:

> Returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN` queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`.

Thus, you need to retrieve the wanted property from the object. In your case, something like: `$row->max_id`